# How can I avoid constructing these grid variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, memory

I have the following calculations in two steps:

1. Initially, I create a set of 4 grid vectors, each spanning from `-2` to `2`:

   ```
   u11grid=[-2:0.1:2];
   u12grid=[-2:0.1:2];
   u22grid=[-2:0.1:2];
   u21grid=[-2:0.1:2];
   [ca, cb, cc, cd] = ndgrid(u11grid, u12grid, u22grid, u21grid);
   u11grid=ca(:);
   u12grid=cb(:);
   u22grid=cc(:);
   u21grid=cd(:);
   %grid=[u11grid u12grid u22grid u21grid]
   sg=size(u11grid,1);
   ```
2. Next, I have an algorithm assigning the same index (`equalorder`) to the rows of `grid` sharing a specific structure:

   ```
   U1grid=[-u11grid -u21grid -u12grid -u22grid  Inf*ones(sg,1) -Inf*ones(sg,1)];
   U2grid=[u21grid-u11grid -u21grid u22grid-u12grid -u22grid Inf*ones(sg,1) -Inf*ones(sg,1)]; 
   s1=size(U1grid,2);
   s2=size(U2grid,2);
   %-------------------------------------------------------
   %sortedU1grid gives U1grid with each row sorted from smallest to largest
   %for each row i of sortedU1grid and for j=1,2,...,s1 index1(i,j) gives
   %the column position 1,2,...,s1 in U1grid(i,:) of sortedU1grid(i,j)

   [sortedU1grid,index1] = sort(U1grid,2); 

   %for each row i of sortedU1grid, d1(i,:) is a 1x(s1-1) row of ones and zeros
   % d1(i,j)=1 if sortedU1grid(i,j)-sortedU1grid(i,j-1)=0 and d1(i,j)=0  otherwise

   d1 = diff(sortedU1grid,[],2) == 0;
   %-------------------------------------------------------
   %Repeat for U2grid
   [sortedU2grid,index2] = sort(U2grid,2);
   d2 = diff(sortedU2grid,[],2) == 0;
   %-------------------------------------------------------
   %Assign the same index to the rows of grid sharing the same "ordering"
   [~,~,equalorder] = unique([index1 index2 d1 d2],'rows', 'stable'); %sgx1
   ```

My question: is there a way to compute the algorithm in step 2 **without the initial construction of the grid vectors in step 1**? I am asking this because step 1 takes a lot of memory given that it basically generates the Cartesian product of 4 sets.

A solution should not rely on the specific content of `U1grid` and `U2grid` as that part changes in my actual code. To be more clear: `U1grid` and `U2grid` are ALWAYS derived from `u11grid, ..., u21grid`; however, the way in which they are derived from `u11grid, ..., u21grid` is slightly more complicated in my actual code from what I have reported here.

Comment: "do not rely for your answer on the specific content of U1grid and U2grid". It means that we also shouldn't rely on the content of `u11grid u12grid ...` grids.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mean that: `U1grid` and `U2grid` are ALWAYS constructed using `u11grid,....,u21grid`. In other words `U1grid` and `U2grid` are ALWAYS functions of  `u11grid,....,u21grid`. What I wanted to say is that the function type could be different from what I have put in the question above.

Comment: `u12grid` and `u22grid` are never used anywhere in the code. Is it normal? If so, you can already save a lot of memory.

Comment: @Bentoy13 they are used in my actual case but not in my example. I've edited to clarify this

Comment: There is always a compromise between speed and memory. In this case, you can exchange memory requirement for time requirement -- simply un-vectorize your code and use loops. Also consider overwriting your arrays for reduced memory footprint (and sometimes speedups too!): `[sortedU1grid,index1] = sort(U1grid,2)` -> `[U1grid,index1] = sort(U1grid,2)`. Some reordering of your code and re-use of variable names throughout might significantly reduce the amount of memory you use.

Comment: @CrisLuengo regarding looping: are you saying that it may be better doing a 4-nested loop?

Comment: 4, or 3, or 2 loops, depending on what your ideal balance between speed and memory usage is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Cris Luengo mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682333/avoid-constructing-initial-grid-of-vectors-in-matlab#comment92376276_52682333), you're always going to be dealing with a trade-off between speed and memory. That said, one option you have is to only compute each of your 4 grid variables (`u11grid u12grid u22grid u21grid`) when needed instead of computing them once and storing them. You will save on memory but will lose speed if you are recomputing each one multiple times.

The solution I came up with involves creating an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) equivalent for each of the 4 grid variables, using combinations of [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) to compute each individually instead of [`ndgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to compute them all together:

```
u11gridFcn = @() repmat((-2:0.1:2).', 41.^3, 1);
u12gridFcn = @() repmat(repelem((-2:0.1:2).', 41), 41.^2, 1);
u22gridFcn = @() repmat(repelem((-2:0.1:2).', 41.^2), 41, 1);
u21gridFcn = @() repelem((-2:0.1:2).', 41.^3);
sg = 41.^4;
```

You would then use these by replacing every usage of your 4 grid variables in `U1grid` and `U2grid` with their corresponding function call. For your specific example above, this would be the new code for `U1grid` and `U2grid` (note also the use of [`inf(...)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inf.html) instead of `Inf*ones(...)`, a small detail):

```
U1grid = [-u11gridFcn() ...
          -u21gridFcn() ...
          -u12gridFcn() ...
          -u22gridFcn() ...
          inf(sg, 1) ...
          -inf(sg, 1)];
U2grid = [u21gridFcn()-u11gridFcn() ...
          -u21gridFcn() ...
          u22gridFcn()-u12gridFcn() ...
          -u22gridFcn() ...
          inf(sg, 1) ...
          -inf(sg, 1)];
```

In this example, you avoid the memory needed to store the 4 grid variables, but the values for `u11grid` and `u12grid` will each be computed twice while the values for `u21grid` and `u22grid` will each be computed three times. Likely a small time trade-off for a potentially significant memory savings.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to remove the `ndgrid`, but it is not the memory bottleneck of this code, which is the call to `unique` on the large matrix `A = [index1 index2 d1 d2]`. The size of `A` is 2825761 by 22 (much larger than the grids), and it seems that `unique` may even internally copy `A`. I was able to avoid this call using

```
    [sorted, ind] = sortrows([index1 index2 d1 d2]);
    change = [1; any(diff(sorted), 2)];
    uniqueInd = cumsum(change);
    equalorder(ind) = uniqueInd;
    [~, ~, equalorder] = unique(equalorder, 'stable');
```

where the last line is still the memory bottleneck and is only needed if you want the same numbering as your code produces. If any unique ordering is okay, you can skip it. You may be able to further reduce the memory footprint by carefully `clear`ing variables are soon as they are no longer needed.

Comment: `sortrows([index1 index2 d1 d2])` still creates that very large matrix `A` you were talking about...

Comment: @CrisLuengo You are correct, but it seems that `unique` does something like copy `A`. At least on my machine, the peak memory of the code I posted is about 1 GB less than the OP. I agree it's not a totally satisfying answer.

Comment: I imagine `sortrows` creates a copy too (the output array). `unique` sorts, so it copies the input, but then it extracts the unique elements, which means it makes a 2nd copy. So I can see how your method reduces peak memory usage. Maybe MATLAB also optimizes out the copy in `sortrows` in this case, as the input is a "temporary", it is not referenced by any variables in the workspace. Interesting...